# jQuery menu if statement malfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, hide

I have a Menu that is not performing correctly. When I want the div that shows up within the menu to hide() after the animation becomes smaller. It doesn't is only disappears for a quick second and then reappears outside the menu. I can't seem to figure out why that is. The menu section is called .title. Thanks for the help.

jQuery

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('video', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady() {
    player.playVideo();
    // Mute!
    player.mute();
}

$(".rotate").textrotator({
    animation: "flip",
    speed: 4000
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var menuBtn   = $(".menuBtn");
    var title     = $(".title");
    var nav       = $("nav"); 
    var navLi     = $("nav").find("li");

    var slideDown = function(){
        if (!title.hasClass("title-element")) {
            title.addClass("title-element", 500);
        };
    };

    var scrollTo = function(place) {
        $(place).animatescroll({
            scrollSpeed: 1000,
            padding: 10
        });
    };

    var close = function(id) {
        if ($("#" + id).is(":visible")) {
            $("#" + id).hide();
            title.delay(250).removeClass("title-element", 500);
            scrollTo('#top');
        }
    };

    var fadeInElement = function(id) {     
        $('#' + id).delay(500).fadeIn(250);
        scrollTo('.title');
    };

    menuBtn.click( function(){
        title.toggleClass("title-menu", 500);
        if (nav.is(":visible")) {
            nav.hide();
        } else {
            nav.delay(500).fadeIn(250);
        }
        $('#about, #works, #contact').filter(":visible").hide();
        title.delay(250).removeClass("title-element", 500);
        scrollTo('#top');
    });

//ABOUT-------------------------------------------------
    $(".about").click( function(){
        slideDown();
        $('#works, #contact').filter(":visible").hide();
        fadeInElement("about");
        close("about");
    });
//WORKS-------------------------------------------------
    $(".works").click( function(){
        slideDown();
        $('#about, #contact').filter(":visible").hide();
        fadeInElement("works");
        close("works");
    });
//CONTACT-----------------------------------------------
    $(".contact").click( function(){
        slideDown();
        $('#about, #works').filter(":visible").hide();
        fadeInElement("contact");
        close("contact");
    });
//------------------------------------------------------
});
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo-bg {
    z-index: 50;
    position: relative;
    top: -230px;
    width: 802px;
    height: 803px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#video {
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -360px;
    width: 720px;
    height: 500px;
}

.title {
    background: url(../img/paper.jpg);
    z-index: 51;
    position: relative;
    top: -470px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -344px;
    width: 695px;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:    5px;
    border-radius:         5px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 0px 7px #000;
    box-shadow:         inset 0px 0px 7px #000;
}

.title-menu {
    height: 80px;
}

.title-element {
    height: 627px;
}

.title p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #F3FFFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0 rgb(210,210,210),-1px 0px 0 rgb(165,165,165),-2px 0px 0 rgb(120,120,120), -3px 0px 0 rgb(75,75,75),-4px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,1),-4px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.menuBtn {
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 328px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 290px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 250ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 250ms ease;
    transition:         all 250ms ease;

    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-2px 1px 1px #777);
    filter: drop-shadow(-2px 1px 1px #777);
}

.menuBtn:active {
    margin-left: 288px;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: none;
}

hr {
    opacity: .3;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
}

nav li {
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    color: #eee;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 153px;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: -1px 0px 1px #000;

    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 250ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 250ms ease;
    transition:         all 250ms ease;
}

nav li:hover {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #444;
}

#about,
#works,
#contact {
    background: red;
    margin: 45px auto 0px auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Modeste Web Studio</title>

<!--Fonts-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/simpletextrotator.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<!--Favicon-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="top"></div>
    <img class="logo-bg" src="img/logo-bg.png" />
    <iframe id="video" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ht2TigJp88w?wmode=opaque&autohide=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=ht2TigJp88w&wmode&start=62&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <img class="menuBtn" src="img/banner.png" />
    <div class="title">
        <p>
            <span class="rotate">MODESTE,BEAUTIFUL,RELIABLE,MODERN</span> WEB <span class="rotate">STUDIO,DESIGN,DEVELOPMENT,SOLUTIONS</span>
        </p>

        <nav>
            <hr>
            <ul>
                <li class="about">ABOUT</li>
                <li class="works">WORKS</li>
                <li>BLOG</li>
                <li class="contact">CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="about">ABOUT</div>
        <div id="works">WORKS</div>
        <div id="contact">CONTACT</div>
    </div>

<!--Javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/animatescroll.noeasing.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.simple-text-rotator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some issues with your CSS and HTML, basically you've set some elements to be floated to the left inside the .title div and the .title div has a fixed height, this resulted in the menu jumping out of the .title div height.

Following is the updated CSS and HTML code that should make the menu work as you've described.

```
<div class="title">
        <p>
            <span class="rotate">MODESTE,BEAUTIFUL,RELIABLE,MODERN</span> WEB <span class="rotate">STUDIO,DESIGN,DEVELOPMENT,SOLUTIONS</span>
        </p>

        <nav>
            <hr>
            <ul>
                <li class="about">ABOUT</li>
                <li class="works">WORKS</li>
                <li>BLOG</li>
                <li class="contact">CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="about">ABOUT</div>
        <div id="works">WORKS</div>
        <div id="contact">CONTACT</div>
    </div>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo-bg {
    z-index: 50;
    position: relative;
    top: -230px;
    width: 802px;
    height: 803px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#video {
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -360px;
    width: 720px;
    height: 500px;
}

.title {
    background: url(../img/paper.jpg);
    z-index: 51;
    position: relative;
    top: -470px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -344px;
    width: 695px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:    5px;
    border-radius:         5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 0px 7px #000;
    box-shadow:         inset 0px 0px 7px #000;
}

.title-menu {
    height: auto;
}

.title-element {
    height: 627px;
}

.title p {
    color: #f3ffff;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0 rgb(210,210,210),-1px 0px 0 rgb(165,165,165),-2px 0px 0 rgb(120,120,120), -3px 0px 0 rgb(75,75,75),-4px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,1),-4px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.menuBtn {
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 328px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 290px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 250ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 250ms ease;
    transition:         all 250ms ease;

    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-2px 1px 1px #777);
    filter: drop-shadow(-2px 1px 1px #777);
}

.menuBtn:active {
    margin-left: 288px;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

hr {
    opacity: .3;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0)); 
}

nav li {
    color: #eeeeee;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Exo 2",sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 1px #000000;
    transition: all 250ms ease 0s;
    width: 20%;

    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 250ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 250ms ease;
    transition:         all 250ms ease;
}

nav li:hover {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #444;
}

#about,
#works,
#contact {
    background: red;
    margin: 45px auto 0px auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This has been useful. It is a better way to structure the html and css. The div inside keeps on reappearing which I think is problem with my jquery.